# How to pass a temp-table to a window from a procedure file

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm using a window(.w) that has a button that passes a variable to a procedure(.p), does its magic and then needs to return the results in a temp-table back to the window for display.

The .w file

Definitions

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE Return_Results
    FIELD tt_var1Return    AS CHARACTER FORMAT "x(20)"
    FIELD tt_var2Return    AS CHARACTER FORMAT "x(30)"
    FIELD tt_var3Return    AS CHARACTER FORMAT "x(30)"
    FIELD tt_var4Return    AS CHARACTER FORMAT "x(30)"
    .
```

Button code

```
ON CHOOSE OF RecordFinder IN FRAME Dialog-Frame 
DO:
    DEFINE VARIABLE varInput AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO 
    DEFINE VARIABLE Return_Results REFERENCE-ONLY. /* <--- I'm pretty sure this is the problem */                

    varInput = Fill-In:SCREEN-VALUE.

    RUN RecordFinder.p(INPUT varInput, OUTPUT Return_Results).

    FOR EACH Return_Results:

        Display Return_Results.

    END.


END.
```

The .p file

i'm omitting some stuff that i think may not be necessary, but it basically takes the input variable, matches it and generates a temp-table from the results and assign those records to a new temp-table that will get passed back.

Definitions

```
DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER windowInput AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO. 
DEFINE OUTPUT PARAMETER Results_Output 

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE Original_tt
    FIELD tt_var1Original    AS CHARACTER FORMAT "x(20)"
    FIELD tt_var2Origianl    AS CHARACTER FORMAT "x(30)"
    FIELD tt_var3Original    AS CHARACTER FORMAT "x(30)"
    FIELD tt_var4Original    AS CHARACTER FORMAT "x(30)"
    .

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE Return_tt
    FIELD tt_var1Return    AS CHARACTER FORMAT "x(20)"
    FIELD tt_var2Return    AS CHARACTER FORMAT "x(30)"
    FIELD tt_var3Return    AS CHARACTER FORMAT "x(30)"
    FIELD tt_var4Return    AS CHARACTER FORMAT "x(30)"
    .


*additional code that works*
```

The next bit of code is for sorting the result of the temp table where it matches the input variable

```
FOR EACH Original_tt WHERE Original_tt.Var1 = windowInput:

    CREATE Return_tt.
    BUFFER-COPY Original_tt TO Results_tt

    Return_tt.tt_var1Return  = Original_tt.tt_var1Original.
    Return_tt.tt_var2Return  = Original_tt.tt_var2Original.
    Return_tt.tt_var3Return  = Original_tt.tt_var3Original.
    Return_tt.tt_var4Return  = Original_tt.tt_var4Original.

    /* This is where I know I'm wrong */
    /* I figured you could assign the Return_tt to the output variable */

    Results_Output = Return_tt.
END.
```

I hope this not too convoluted.

Answer (score 2):

The doc at https://docs.progress.com/bundle/abl-reference/page/Parameter-passing-syntax.html has detail on the parameter passing syntax (though no decent example).

In the called program (.p) you need to define the parameters

```
DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER windowInput AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO. 
DEFINE OUTPUT PARAMETER TABLE FOR Return_tt.
```

In the caller (.w), you say the following

```
RUN RecordFinder.p(INPUT varInput, OUTPUT TABLE Return_Results).
```

Now you have the data in your caller.

It's a deep copy (so the .W gets its very own copy in memory). This may cause you performance problems (since a copy must be made), although there are reasons for making deep copies too.

You can turn the deep (by value) call into a shallow (by reference) call quite easily.

```
RUN RecordFinder.p(INPUT varInput, OUTPUT TABLE Return_Results BY-REFERENCE).
```

Some further doc at https://docs.progress.com/bundle/develop-abl/page/Passing-a-temp-table-by-reference.html . You don't need to define the temp-table as `REFERENCE-ONLY` in the caller.